# How to make a short and long version of a required argument using Python Argparse?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I want to specify a required argument called `inputdir` but I also would like to have a shorthand version of it called `i`. I don't see a concise solution to do this without making both optional arguments and then doing my own check. Is there a preferred practice for this that I'm not seeing or the only way is to make both optional and do my own error-handling?

Here is my code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("inputdir", help="Specify the input directory")
parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

For *flags* (options starting with `-` or `--`) pass in options *with* the flags. You can specify multiple options:

```
parser.add_argument('-i', '--inputdir', help="Specify the input directory")
```

See the [*name or flags* option documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags):

> The `add_argument()` method must know whether an optional argument, like `-f` or `--foo`, or a positional argument, like a list of filenames, is expected. The first arguments passed to `add_argument()` must therefore be either a series of flags, or a simple argument name.

Demo:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('-i', '--inputdir', help="Specify the input directory")
_StoreAction(option_strings=['-i', '--inputdir'], dest='inputdir', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='Specify the input directory', metavar=None)
>>> parser.print_help()
usage: [-h] [-i INPUTDIR]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i INPUTDIR, --inputdir INPUTDIR
                        Specify the input directory
>>> parser.parse_args(['-i', '/some/dir'])
Namespace(inputdir='/some/dir')
>>> parser.parse_args(['--inputdir', '/some/dir'])
Namespace(inputdir='/some/dir')
```

However, the first element for *required* arguments is just a placeholder. `-` and `--` options are *always* optional (that's the command line convention), required arguments are never specified with such switches. Instead the command-line help will show where to put required arguments with a placeholder based on the first argument passed to `add_argument()`, which is to be passed in without dashes.

If you have to break with that convention and use an argument starting with `-` or `--` that is required *anyway*, you'll have to do your own checking:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
if not args.inputdir:
    parser.error('Please specify an inputdir with the -i or --inputdir option')
```

Here the [`parser.error()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.error) will print the help information together with your error message, then exit.

Comment: The thing that I don't like, is that when it prints out the usage, it doesn't print out `-i` and `--inputdir`. I would want the usage to be something like `usage: [-h] [-i|--inputdir INPUTDIR]`; something to that effect. Probably one way to do it is to use `add_mutually_exclusive_group()`, but that seems a little hacky to me. I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: @searchengine27: you'd have to customise the [help formatter class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#formatter-class), I fear.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#required

required=True should support making the argument required

Comment: This is a bad solution - clearly not best practice for the situation asked by OP.