# Python short and long argument parser

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like to add some command line switches to my script, to which I use the argparse.

The related part of my script so far looks like:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="Hola python",description="Hola")
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', help="helpppping")
parser.print_help()
```

However this results in:

```
usage: Hola python [-h] [-i INPUT]

Hola

optional arguments:
-h, --help            show this help message and exit
-i INPUT, --input INPUT
                    helpppping
```

My concerns is with this row

```
-i INPUT, --input INPUT
```

This should looks like

```
 -i, --input         helppppping
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638813/how-to-make-a-short-and-long-version-of-a-required-argument-using-python-argpars) question, and read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags) part of the manual, and all seems good but still not formatted well.

I obviously miss something just don't know what.

Comment: So you basically want `-i` to work like a switch, and not take any argument after it?

Comment: Well it should be followed with string to the input file, I just saw in many scripts that there are a short and a long version of the switch and both do the same.

Comment: And they do. Have you tried using this?

Comment: I believe you did correctly and it does what you want. You just misunderstand the help message. The helpppping text appears next line due to formatting, and the text says -i INPUT, --input INPUT rather than -i, --input INPUT, well, because that's the way it is. But functionaly, I think you're fine.

Comment: To my understanding add_argument first take a list of flags. So the '-short_version', '--long_version' should work, but its not. I'm a little confused.

Comment: But what does not work? Please show a failure test case.

Comment: Based on the accepted answer your concern apparently is with the formatting the help line, not with actual parsing of inputs.  If the `metavar` fix isn't enough (such as an extra space), look at past questions on the same topic, [python argparse help message, disable metavar for short options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936145)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', metavar='', help='helping')
```

Comment: Gosh, that was quick. It works now, so I forgot to include the rest of the params? :O

Comment: Thanks yes there are some formatter_class that you can use checkout this https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: So @SecThor you're just bothered by the fact the help reads 'INPUT'?! This is just cosmetic. I don't think there's a point addressing this and if I were you I'd leave it the way it is because this is what people are used to see. It doesn't matter either way, though.

Comment: I agree with you, this was just cosmetic, but my OCD forced me to fix it :)

Comment: @Jérôme yes you are correct in my case my team tester want we to fix this and he has no idea about CLI tools it's very irritating sometimes

Comment: Why did you add the `required=True` and `type=str` option?  Adding `required=True` changes the intent of the code that @SecThor presented, and `type=str` just adds noise because it is the default behavior.  The only thing that needed to be added was `metavar=''`.